# Cleaning Up Dataframe: NA, Decimals, Strings, Mixtures,

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a data.frame which I would like to work on in R. It's totally messed up! I focus on 1 column, it should contain numerical values. Of course there are some NAs, but also Strings (e.g. "none", "no thanks") and beyond that there are numerical answer like "<1" and "1-2". Decimal separators sometimes are "." and ",".

How can I deal with all those problems? I don't need any imputations yet. Is there a command to ignore all non-numerical rows for this one column in R?

**Update**

```
# convert all decimal separators
group <- lapply(group, function(x) sub(',', '.', x))
# transform any non-numeric into NA 
group <- lapply(group, as.numeric)
# remove all old and new NAs
group <- data.frame(group)  
group_final <- na.omit(group)
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: `as.numeric` produces `NA`-values for everything that is not recognized as numeric. Why not combine this with `na.omit` afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `na.strings` in the `read.csv/read.table`.  It can take values as a vector.  For example,

```
 df1 <- read.csv('yourfile.csv', na.strings=c('none', 'no thanks'))
```

This will not take care of the `"<1"`, `"1-2"` etc.  It is not clear how the OP wanted to deal with those.  If the decimal separators needs to be changed to a single one, try

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) sub(',', '.', x))
```

Comment: The original data is rather complex, is there a way for "na.strings" to work on my subsequent single data.frame column?

Comment: @Mac  As I said in the solution, this will not take care off everything.  If you have specific values that needs to be changed to NA, it can be specified in the `na.strings`.  But, if the values are `<1`, `<5`, etc, after you read the dataset, `as.numeric(df1$yourcolumn)` will change those non-numeric to `NA`

Comment: I'm sry, it's long time ago I used R. as.numeric returns an error "Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'". In principle I would like to remove/transform all non-numerics in one step and delete them in a second step. But there seems to be a small problem :/

Comment: @Mac You cannot use the `as.numeric` on the whole dataset, instead try `lapply(df1, as.numeric)`, there will be a friendly warning

Comment: Ah ok, this works! And in case I want to transform "," into "." in advance, in order not to loose those data? I should use sub(',', '.', x)? Can you give me a small explanation how this functions works? Thank you very much

Comment: @Mac In the pattern, argument we specify the `,` to match, and we replace it with `.` in `sub`.

Comment: Each functions makes sense to me, but in the end, it's still not working correct. There are some NAs left in the data, hmm

Comment: @Mac There will be `NAs`  as the `as.numeric` converts non-numeric elements to NA.

Comment: But how can I delete those in the last step? group_final <- na.omit(group) seems not to work